# Cassandra: thousands of records to insert

Tags: performance, cassandra, cql3, nosql

I'm using Cassandra with C++ driver and I have observed a very slow performance when coming to insert thousands of rows. I am using a VM Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with 8Go Ram and 4CPUs.

I have got an ascii file which contains 15800 records and I'm trying to read each record and fill my cassandra db table with. The "COPY" command took around 1min 30sec. With querying after reading each record one by one took around 6-7mins and with a batch query it takes for ever (lasted 30 mins then I abandonned!).

I would like to know if there is any solution for such kind of insertion with a faster performance.

Many thanks!

Comment: There's not quite enough info here to tell. I'd start by getting some more detailed metrics - a single metric across the whole process doesn't pinpoint what activity is slow. Put some timing around each activity, and find out what the biggest contributors are.

Comment: You also need to share some code, so we can see if there are any obvious errors like a new session or prepared statement for each insert.

Comment: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tracing_r.html

Comment: I used sstableloader utility to import huge amount of data within a few minutes, does require some fiddling though.

Comment: Does your Ubuntu VM have a mount point for swap?  On a Cassandra (Linux) server, swap should be completely disabled.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: swap is disabled!

Comment: @Tinux: can you please provide a tutorial or an example of how it's done with the sstableloader ? Thanks :)

Comment: @Mikhail Stepura: Thanks for the link, it's very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduce the time lapse to 12.5 secs by slicing the batch. Here is the solution, if it can help others and I would be happy if some one else could provide a better one :)

```
int nb_lines = 0;
int rest = 0;
string create_query = "BEGIN BATCH ";
std::ifstream file("/media/sf_Shared/xfmge");
for(string line; getline(file, line);){
    stringstream sstm;
    if(nb_lines  == 800 ) {
        nb_lines = 0;
        rest = 0;
        create_query += " APPLY BATCH;";
        boost::shared_ptr<cql::cql_query_t> create(
            new cql::cql_query_t(create_query, cql::CQL_CONSISTENCY_ONE));
        query_result = session->query(create);

        query_result.wait();
        if (query_result.get().error.is_err()) {
            cout << "-isbuild - ERROR for query: " << create_query << endl;
            cout << query_result.get().error.message << endl;
            return iserrno;
        } else {
            cout << "+isbuild - QUERY SUCCESSFUL: " << create_query << endl;
        }
        create_query = "BEGIN BATCH ";
    } else {
        record = (char*)line.c_str();
        sstm << "insert into felder (id, data) values ('felder', '" << record << "') ";
        create_query += sstm.str();
        rest = 1;
    }
    nb_lines ++;
}
if(rest == 1){
    create_query += " APPLY BATCH";
    boost::shared_ptr<cql::cql_query_t> create(
        new cql::cql_query_t(create_query, cql::CQL_CONSISTENCY_ONE));
    query_result = session->query(create);

    query_result.wait();
    if (query_result.get().error.is_err()) {
        cout << "-isbuild - ERROR for query: " << create_query << endl;
        cout << query_result.get().error.message << endl;
        return iserrno;
    } else {
        cout << "+isbuild - QUERY SUCCESSFUL: " << create_query << endl;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my source code:

```
string create_query = "BEGIN BATCH ";
std::ifstream file("/media/sf_Shared/xfmge");
for(string line; getline(file, line);){
    stringstream sstm;
    record = (char*)line.c_str();
    sstm << "insert into felder (id, data) values ('felder', '" << record << "') ";
    create_query += sstm.str();
}
create_query += " APPLY BATCH;";

boost::shared_ptr<cql::cql_query_t> create(
        new cql::cql_query_t(create_query, cql::CQL_CONSISTENCY_ONE));
query_result = session->query(create);
cout << "sending..." << endl;
query_result.wait();
if (query_result.get().error.is_err()) {
    cout << "-isbuild - ERROR in query: " << create_query << endl;
    cout << query_result.get().error.message << endl;
    return iserrno;
} else {
    cout << "+isbuild - QUERY SUCCESSFUL: " << create_query << endl;
}
```